# Merge two rows into single row with addition

Tags: sql

```
 2  abc ds  a@gmail.com 123 2000.00 1500.00 500.00  0.00    0.00    0.00    500.00
 2  abc ds  a@gmail.com 123 0.00    0.00    0.00    500.00  200.00  300.00  300.00
```

I want to display this as a single row with addition of last column.

Comment: So you want to group by the first column? What should happen with the other columns?

Comment: Show us the whole expected result!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you need to use a simple Group By method and decide what you want each of your columns to do.

I'm assuming you want the max value for each column except the last where you want the Sum of the values. To achieve this you need to use something like this:

```
Select colA, max(colB), max(colC), max(colD), max(colE), max(colF), max(colG), sum(colLast)
from table
group by colA
```